# SSRS 401 unauthorized when connecting to data source

Tags: reporting-services, service, report, unauthorized

I have searched google and stack overflow before making this post, but i might have missed the answer to my issue.

I have an SSRS report server installed on a server hosting MS SQL server as well. The 2 services is working together just fine and I can do what i expect to do.

The issue is that when my colleagues are trying to connect to the report server URL through Report Builder, they cannot get access. They receive 401 unauthorized error. If they use my login on their machine, they still get no access.
If i use their login on my machine, it works fine.

My conclusion is that its not their logins that is causing this error, and it is not the server configuration either as i can login just fine (i am admin and in the admin AD group, but so is 1 of my colleagues who cant get access).
It must be something on their machine, but i just dont know what or where to look.

Thank you in regards.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to navigate to your SSRS website and assign `Report Builder` to your colleague's domain\user account.

See here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-report-builder-access?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Click%20the%20gear%20icon%20on,Otherwise%2C%20click%20New%20Role%20Assignment.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-report-builder-access?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Click%20the%20gear%20icon%20on,Otherwise%2C%20click%20New%20Role%20Assignment.)